# Unable to SSH between machines on the same network

Tags: wireless-networking, router, ssh, lan, mobile-broadband

I'm trying to SSH from my laptop (`mac` / `192.168.1.114`) to my pc (`linux` / `192.168.1.199`). Both are connected, via wifi, to a 4g router (Huawei b715-23c). I have `sshd` running on `linux` on port `4773`, and have been able to do SSH via private IPs when both devices were connected to a different home network.

Under this new network, I am no longer able to SSH from `mac` to `linux`. IP addresses are correct for the new network. I am also unable to ping `linux` from `mac`

from ARP table of `mac`:

```bash
arp -a
[...]
? (192.168.1.199) at (incomplete) on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
[...]
```

I am also unable to ping `linux` from `mac` (but I am able to ping the router, or the mac's own private IP address):

```bash
PING 192.168.1.199 (192.168.1.199): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
[...]
Request timeout for icmp_seq 5
ping: sendto: No route to host
Request timeout for icmp_seq 6
ping: sendto: Host is down
```

I have also tried port forwarding port `4773` to `192.168.1.199:4773`and SSHing via the public IP, which hasn't worked either.

Information from my ISP about the APN used by the router indicates that port 4773 isn't blocked by the ISP.

Any help would be appreciated. Existing posts on superuser weren't able to solve this. The router has no configuration option regarding AP isolation.

I would be happy via a solution using either public/private IP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the APN was using a NAT public IP, changed to an APN with a public IP and also restarted the router, either one of these allowed me to SSH via private IP.

Answer (score 0):

It probably has nothing to do with the SSH setup since it works on another Wifi LAN.
The problem is most likely the Wifi network itself.

I presume this Wifi router has a setting called "Client Isolation" enabled. (It may have a different name in your router.)
This setting prevents clients talking to each other, but they can talk to the router and get to the internet.
(Not being able to ping is also indicative of this.)
Disable that setting and everything should work.

PS. Client isolation has it uses on a guest network were you may have "untrusted" devices, but on a private network it usually only gets in the way.

Comment: I'm guessing this may be the issue, but my router has no option related to that  unfortunately.